# Название картин

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно подписывать автора и название под картиной. Через запятую, точку, тире или нет необходимости в постановке знака? Например. Леонардо да Винчи «Мона Лиза».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если посмотреть  альбомы с репродукциями, то видно, что все записи  разделяются точками, например:

И.И. Шишкин. Сосны, освещенные солнцем. Этюд. 1886 г.

Рембрандт. Возвращение блудного сына. 262×206 см. Масло, холст. ок.1668-1669 гг.

Answer (score 5):

Согласно Справочнику Мильчина принцип оформления подписей в изданиях по изобразительному искусству такой: все элементы подписи, за исключением названия материала и техники исполнения, разделяют точкой.

Возможно выделение курсивом отдельных элементов подписи.

Примерная схема подписи: Имя и фамилия художника. Название произведения. Дата создания. Место хранения (Город. Название музея или только название музея, если в него входит прилагательное, образованное от названия города).

Эль Греко. Снятие пятой печати. Около 1610-1641. Нью-Йорк. Метрополитен музей

И пример с курсивом:

Тициан. Автопортрет. Около 1565. *Холст, масло*. 86х65. Мадрид. *Прадо*

Comment: Небольшая поправка: точка в конце подписи не ставится. Исправила.